# RStudio: Statement to clear memory

Tags: r

I'm still getting used to R and have an assignment coming up.

This is one of the first questions: Put a statement at the top of your code that will clear the memory and ensure that all variables that may have been used in a previous session, are deleted from the memory.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: `rm(list = ls())` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: That is a dangerous statement since it will delete *everything* -- even things that you might want to save. Routinely putting it in code is a bad idea.